# How to Use jQuery in a inline script when jQuery was imported in a react app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've been learning react and have a simple question.

I created an app component which is working well.

I installed jQuery using `npm` and `import jquery` in app component `import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'`

At index.html file I have a script tag injecting a script.js and I'd like to use jQuery in it. But neither $ nor jQuery has been recognized.

What should be done to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think your node modules jquery not loading in index.html, you can use jquery by link like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or put your jquery code in the related component, there you can easily import your jquery package.

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```